# whatsapp-web.js RemoteAuth con SQLSERVER O ARCHIVO LOCAL

Tags: nodejs, api, whatsapp-web

Estoy tratando de tener un api en NODE.JS con conexion a RemoteAuth a whatsapp-we.js para el envio de mensajes  pero quiero tener varios usuario almacenados en el mismo api estoy tratando de realizarlo con sqlserver sin embargo cuando trato de invocar metodos como mostrar el qr el sistema se salta la instruccion, y de igual manera lo trate de hacer con almacenamiento local en un archivo sin embargo en los 2 metodos me dice que se debe de utilizar el store de mongodb.

Quiera saber si alguien ha podido conectarse por medio de alguna de esas opciones y que me de una guia.

Saludos,